# Series with multiple variables, convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $D$ be the region in the $xy$-plane in which the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {{{(x+2y)}^k}\over{k}}$$

converges. Then what kind of region is the interior of $D$ ?

My instinct tells me to use the "finding the radius of convergence" technique from calculus to solve this problem, but it has both $x$ and $y$, and I'm not quite sure what I got.

I have $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \left|{k(x+2y) \over k}\right| = |(x+2y)|<1$$

What kind of region is this ?

I want to say that it is two parallel lines, but I'm not sure if I'm even doing this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you are really being asked two questions - one about $\sum z^n/n$ (the log series in fact) and one about what the region $ |x+2y|<1$ looks like. You're also right that the boundary is a pair of parallel lines.

To see this, write out more concretely $-1<x+2y<1$. Your region is the infinite rectangular strip contained by the lines $x+2y=\pm 1$.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes sense. Thank you !

Comment: No worries! Easy to be bamboozled with $|\cdot|$ signs everywhere.